Firefox cannot read file from VirtualBox shared folder
I am using a VirtualBox machine, both host and guest are Ubuntu 23.04.
I have mounted a shared folder in the host :
$ sudo df -aTh | egrep "shared|Filesystem"
Filesystem     Type             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
shared         vboxsf           425G  400G   26G  95% /home/iutuser/vboxshared

All files in there belong to root/vboxsf and have 770 access rights:
$ ls -alh /home/iutuser/vboxshared | grep test.html
-rwxrwx---  1 root    vboxsf    22 juin  30 23:37 test.html

My user is iutuser, it belongs to the group vboxsf, listed as file owner:
$ sudo cat /etc/gshadow | grep vboxsf
vboxsf:!::iutuser

I run firefox as iutuser:
iutuser     3019    2759  1 23:36 pts/0    00:00:18 /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/firefox
iutuser     3192    3019  0 23:36 pts/0    00:00:00 /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -parentBuildID 20240626001103 -prefsLen 34206 -prefMapSize 245537 -appDir /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/browser {e582a6f3-d0a2-4557-a2fc-4e8300da164a} 3019 true socket
iutuser     3211    3019  0 23:36 pts/0    00:00:01 /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 1 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 35166 -prefMapSize 245537 -jsInitLen 234488 -parentBuildID 20240626001103 -greomni /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja -appDir /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/browser {0e7b0c83-22b7-404d-8adb-5ed327594fe3} 3019 true tab
iutuser     3330    3019  0 23:36 pts/0    00:00:09 /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 39952 -prefMapSize 245537 -jsInitLen 234488 -parentBuildID 20240626001103 -greomni /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja -appDir /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/browser {fccfb776-21b6-4427-adbc-d0ab1bf42f83} 3019 true tab
iutuser     3493    3019  0 23:36 pts/0    00:00:00 /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -parentBuildID 20240626001103 -sandboxingKind 0 -prefsLen 40059 -prefMapSize 245537 -appDir /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/browser {e4b798e4-f60b-4eca-a99b-90eb28bff62c} 3019 true utility
iutuser     3546    3019  0 23:36 pts/0    00:00:00 /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 5 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 31797 -prefMapSize 245537 -jsInitLen 234488 -parentBuildID 20240626001103 -greomni /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja -appDir /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/browser {44f9bf12-12eb-4f10-94b3-569de4b95045} 3019 true tab
iutuser     3796    3019  0 23:37 pts/0    00:00:00 /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 7 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 32070 -prefMapSize 245537 -jsInitLen 234488 -parentBuildID 20240626001103 -greomni /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja -appDir /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/browser {3cf62206-87b0-4688-8da8-eda498606af9} 3019 true tab
iutuser     3826    3019  0 23:37 pts/0    00:00:00 /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 8 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 32070 -prefMapSize 245537 -jsInitLen 234488 -parentBuildID 20240626001103 -greomni /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja -appDir /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/browser {cb2a7f65-74d1-425f-be7d-f79eaa0e35ab} 3019 true tab
iutuser     3848    3019  0 23:37 pts/0    00:00:00 /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 9 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 40359 -prefMapSize 245537 -jsInitLen 234488 -parentBuildID 20240626001103 -greomni /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja -appDir /snap/firefox/4483/usr/lib/firefox/browser {351c6022-31d5-439a-ba25-2affa1dd8e67} 3019 true tab

But Firefox says that it cannot open the file file:///home/iutuser/vboxshared/test.html:



While cat can read the file as expected:
$ cat /home/iutuser/vboxshared/test.html
<html>
    Hello
</html>

With help from @steeldriver and these SO posts:

How do I access mounted hard drive with a Snap application?
Ubuntu 20.04 snaps: Allow a snap app access to a VM shared folder

I understand that the issue lays with snap and AppArmor, see the kernel log:
[  320.509463] audit: type=1400 audit(1719786105.705:114): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/home/iutuser/vboxshared/test.html" pid=3298 comm=53747265616D5472616E73202334 requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

I am not familiar with these applications. What and how should I configure so my snap Firefox is allowed to read my shared files?
I would like to fix it and not just reinstall Firefox from apt.

Is the removable-media connection enabled for the snap? see for example How do I access mounted hard drive with a Snap application?

Thanks for the suggestion, it helped me investigate further: the issue seems linked to snap and AppArmor, I add these info to the original post. But adding removable-media does not solve the issue.

Ubuntu 23.04 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Don't forget that your release-upgrade path (to 23.10) will disappear in a few days, as Ubuntu 23.10 will reach EOL in mere days with its warning notices having gone out weeks ago. Ubuntu 23.04 has one upgrade path, to 23.10, and that will soon be gone.

Understood, please let me replicate on 22.04.
